# Supervisor won't automatically startup when Ubuntu Server is booted

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, supervisord, beanstalkd

I'm working on beantalkd and supervisord for my Laravel project with homestead vm. Everytime i vagrant up the homestead vm, the supervisord does not start. I have to manually type below for it to run:

```
sudo service supervisor start
```

The version i'm running on is 3.0b2-1. I have also installed rcconf to check which service is started automatically at boot time and supervisor is checked as well.

Another thing that i tried is running crontab to try to start the service. Below is the crontab script i wrote:

```
@reboot root /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
* * * * * php /home/vagrant/projects/llpm/artisan scheduled:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 --env=local
```

Still it won't automatically start at reboot. Anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the answer from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162937/debian-wheezy-supervisor-install-from-repostiory-not-start-automatically-on-b).

Somehow, it's caused by vagrant. So what i did is added this line below to Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "service supervisor restart", run: "always"
```

Vagrant up and supervisor is booted up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use: `supervisord -c '/etc/supervisord.conf'` 
in place of: `/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` which points to a config file that supervisor does not use (`/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`). 
I hope it helps.